# order a record by date field's month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello I have a table in mssql 2008 that contains a date field. 
I'd like to make a select statement which will list all members, sorted by month only.
how do I access only the month part of the date field?

here are some of the member table fields:

```
    id varchar(9) primary key,
f_name varchar(20),
l_name varchar(20),
f_name_english varchar(20),
l_name_english varchar(20),
gender varchar(20),
experience int,
b_date date,
passport varchar(20),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT    id
        , f_name
        , l_name
        , f_name_english
        , l_name_english
        , gender
        , experience
        , b_date
        , passport 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY MONTH(b_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `month()` function. (or `datepart(month, b_date)`)

```
Select id, f_name, l_name....
From YourTableName
Order by month(b_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE T
ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,T.b_date)
```

Include `DATEPART(YEAR,T.b_date)` to `ORDER BY` if you want to order a result by year too

Answer (score 0):

this will sort by year & month

```
SELECT 
    id, f_name, l_name....
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY
    CONVERT(Nvarchar(7), b_date, 121)
    --or use DatePart(Month, b_date)
    -- if you don't care about the year.
```